# document viewer presentation mode show small frame when display scale is 200%

Tags: 20.04, evince

When I try to open a document in presentation mode in document viewer in Ubuntu 20.04 while the display scale is set to 200%, the presentation is shown in a small frame in the middle of the screen. If I change the display scale to 100% again the presentation is filling the whole screen as expected.

Is there any fix for that, or should I file a bug report somewhere?

Comment: Having the same issue with fractional scaling of 125%

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evince shows small frame in Presentation mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1260803/evince-shows-small-frame-in-presentation-mode)

Comment: Yes, It does. Thank you. !